# Self Learning Neural network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, keras

Is it possible for a neural network to learn based on its own predictions? So what I really want to do is to have my neural network model to learn from its own predictions but I'm not sure what the implications would be. On my own intuition, I think that it might lead the model into a state where it doesn't work well with new input since what it knows too much only about itself. I would want any advice for the matter.

Also I thought of having the model learn from its own predictions that pass a certain uncertainty. But I also have a hard time determining uncertainty for a neural network model and Im using keras.

[image: A workflow of what Im trying to]

Comment: Is this unsupervised learning ? It seems that you are training the model to be more confident about predictions that it might not have been confident about. This will very likely lead to bad solutions.

Comment: No I have labelled data. So the model's predictions is based on my labelled data. after the model predicts new and unlabelled data, I would like to use them (the predictions that pass the certainty threshhold) as part of my training data for the model to improve the model.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible for a neural network to learn based on its own predictions?

This is called a recurrent neural network (RNN).

> On my own intuition, I think that it might lead the model into a state where it doesn't work well with new input since what it knows too much only about itself.

Not very clear what you are stating here, but it sounds like you might want to check out Hopfield Networks, a specific type of neural network which have a tendency to converge towards stable local minimum states, and considered to be closer to the way human memory works than standard feedforward neural networks.

> Also I thought of having the model learn from its own predictions that pass a certain uncertainty.

Check Boltzmann Machines, a probabilistic version of Hopfield Networks.

> But I also have a hard time determining uncertainty for a neural network model and Im using keras.

Again, not very clear what you are asking. But you can create RNN in Keras, and Boltzmann Machines with TensorFlow.

Comment: I edited my question to add a workflow on what I meant by training with its own predictions.

Comment: @VincentPakson Yup, it's seems like you're looking for a variation on Hopfiled Nets or Boltzman Machines.

Comment: With that. I'd love to have more idea on how to use Hopfield or Bolzmann Machines in my use case

Comment: I don't see how this is recurrent, there are no input sequences. I also don't see how this is Boltzmann machines as there is no low-rank optimization...

Comment: @Curious seq-to-seq or seq-to-vec are only one application of RNN. Any NNet where the outputs feed back into the network are RNN. The dynamics of the network described in the OP are similar to the way Hopfiled and Boltzmann converge to stable attractors/local energy minima, even if the way the OP formulates it is completes different.

Comment: He is basically training a feed-forward network while changing the target values each epoch. You can call it RNN if the backpropagation considers more than one forward pass on the same datapoint in one big step, which doesn't in this case. What he is suggesting is the pseudo-labeling approach (in section 3 in https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/09/pseudo-labelling-semi-supervised-learning-technique/ ) which is an old method for semi-supervised learning.

Answer (score 0):

Idk if this is what you are looking for, but this looks a little bit like semisupervised learning, which I'd check out. You start with a few labeled observations, but then you can feed the most certain (unlabeled) predictions back in as if they were actuals in order to supplement the small amount of data you do have.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-supervised_learning